# How can I control the outliner's length in Python turtle?

Tags: python, module, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am making an analog clock with python, using turtle module.

I could configue a window size and a circle, But i can't finish outliner of a circle.

I didn't give any integer to get the complete ouliner. But it doesn't surround a circle entire.

Please, tell me if there is a something missing.

```
window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(1000, 800)
window.bgcolor("black")
window.title("Analog Clock")
window.tracer(0)

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.color("#FFD700")

t.penup()
t.speed(0)
t.pensize(25)
t.hideturtle()
t.goto(0, -290)
t.pendown()
t.fillcolor("white")
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(300, 360)
t.end_fill()
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of `tracer()` without any call to `update()`.  You can either remove the `window.tracer(0)` line, or add a `window.update()` line after your `t.end_fill()` line.

I usually recommend avoiding `tracer()` and `update()` until you have your code basically working, just to avoid bugs like this.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1000, 800)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title("Analog Clock")
screen.tracer(0)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # no-op if `tracer(0)`
turtle.color('#FFD700')
turtle.pensize(25)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-290)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.fillcolor('white')

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(300)
turtle.end_fill()

screen.update()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have another question.
I read the turtle library page. And there is a mention about the tracer() and update(); update() is used when tracer is turned off. 
I put the 0 as argument for tracer(). So, It's treated as turned off, I guess. 
But, why do I have to put fastest as argument for speed(), instead of 0?? 
According to turtle library page, 0 is same as fastest.

Comment: @SeowooJang, you can use 0 or `'fastest'` as the argument to `speed()`, the latter better documents your intention.  When tracing is *off*, i.e. `tracer(0)` then `speed()` doesn't matter as it's the speed of tracing.  I tend to use `tracer(False)` which is a Python2-ism but better documents I'm turning tracing off.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem with your posted code working properly :)

```
window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(1000, 800)
window.bgcolor("black")
window.title("Analog Clock")

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.color("#FFD700")

t.penup()
t.speed(0)
t.pensize(25)
t.hideturtle()
t.goto(0, -290)
t.pendown()
t.fillcolor("white")
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(300, 360)
t.end_fill()

window.update()
```

Comment: @Seowoo Jang If with my answer (or someone else's answer) you have solved your problem, I am sending you to mark an answer as a solution with a green tick. Hello :)